# EasyMock: Void Methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, void, easymock

I have a method that returns void in a class that is a dependency of the class I want to test.

This class is huge and I'm only using this single method from it.
I need to replace the implementation of this method for the test as I want it to do something different and I need to be able to access the parameters this method receives.

I cannot find a way of doing this in [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/). I think I know how to do it with [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/) by using [`doAnswer`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.5/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doAnswer(org.mockito.stubbing.Answer)) but I don't want to add another library unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do correctly, you should be able to use `andAnswer()`:

```
mockObject.someMethod(eq(param1), eq(param2));
expectLastCall().andAnswer(new IAnswer() {
    public Object answer() {
        //supply your mock implementation here...
        SomeClass arg1 = (SomeClass) getCurrentArguments()[0];
        AnotherClass arg2 = (AnotherClass) getCurrentArguments()[1];
        arg1.doSomething(blah);
        //return the value to be returned by the method (null for void)
        return null;
    }
});
```

The [EasyMock User Guide](http://easymock.org/user-guide.html) explains:

> #### Creating Return Values or Exceptions
>
> Sometimes we would like our mock object to return a value or throw an exception that is created at the time of the actual call. Since EasyMock 2.2, the object returned by [`expectLastCall()`](http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/EasyMock.html#expectLastCall--) and [`expect(T value)`](http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/EasyMock.html#expect-T-) provides the method [`andAnswer(IAnswer answer)`](http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/IExpectationSetters.html#andAnswer-org.easymock.IAnswer-) which allows [you] to specify an implementation of the interface [`IAnswer`](http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/IAnswer.html) that is used to create the return value or exception.
>
> Inside an [`IAnswer`](http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/IAnswer.html) callback, the arguments passed to the mock call are available via [`EasyMock.getCurrentArguments()`](http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/EasyMock.html#getCurrentArguments--). If you use these, refactorings like reordering parameters may break your tests. You have been warned.

Answer (score 23):

If you just call the void method for each time you're expecting it to be invoked and then invoke `EasyMock.expectLastCall()` prior to calling `replay()`, Easymock will “remember” each invocation.

So I don’t think you need to explicitly call `expect()` (other than `lastCall`) since you’re not expecting anything from a void method, except its invocation.

Thanks Chris!

[“Fun With EasyMock”](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=43) by fellow StackOverflow user [Burt Beckwith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/160313/burt-beckwith) is a good blog post that provides more detail. Notable excerpt:

> Basically the flow that I tend to use is:
>
> 1. Create a mock
> 2. call `expect(mock.[method call]).andReturn([result])` for each expected call
> 3. call `mock.[method call]`, then `EasyMock.expectLastCall()` for each expected void call
> 4. call `replay(mock)` to switch from “record” mode to “playback” mode
> 5. inject the mock as needed
> 6. call the test method
> 7. call `verify(mock)` to assure that all expected calls happened

Comment: I think this answer doesn't address the question - he doesn't want to just assert an expectation on the method, but also replace it's implementation.

Comment: Good point Matt, on the other hand this post helped me to realise why the expect-method isn't really applicapable here.

Answer (score 5):

If you only want access to the parameters for later, you might also appreciate the [Captures](http://easymock.org/api/easymock/2.4/org/easymock/Capture.html) class which is new to EasyMock 2.4.

You can use an instance of the "Capture" class in place of a matcher. When your mocked method is invoked, the Capture instance will store the parameter it was invoked with.

```
Capture<ChartPanel> captured = new Capture<ChartPanel>();
// setChartPanel is going to be called during execution;
// we want to verify some things about the ChartPanel
// instance it's invoked with
chartMock.setChartPanel(capture(captured));
replay(chartMock);

ufdm.setChartAnnotater(chartMock);
// afterPropertiesSet triggers the setChartPanel call...
ufdm.afterPropertiesSet();
verify(chartMock);

// verify some things about the ChartPanel parameter our
// mock object was invoked with
assertSame(plot, captured.getValue().getChart().getPlot());
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out PowerMock. EasyMock is based on the proxy reflection API meaning everything is a proxy and you can only test interfaces, and thus only non-final methods and classes. This might work for some, but if you're testing the world as built, you'll need more power.

With PowerMock the Java 5 instrumentation API removes the limitations. No need to write mock object implementations of the object to be tested (just ugly IMO). Couple PowerMock with Mockito (or JMockit) and you'll really be off to the races.

Of course, there is the other direction of rewriting your code to be more easily tested, which is generally a good idea too, if possible.

Answer (score -1):

In situations like these I've found that making a nested class in my unit test class and overriding the methods with special requirements in that way is the best route. So if you're testing `ClassA` which has that method with the parameters you need to access, you'd do something like:

```
class MockClassA extends ClassA {
    @Override
    void specialMethod(String param1, String param2) {
        // do logging or manipulation of some sort
        super.specialMethod(param1,param2); // if you need to
    }
}
```

In my unit testing code, I then just use this instance instead. Just treat it as if it was any other mock object. Much easier than mixing libraries, which I agree is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Already considered it. But it is an abstract class, so I would need to provide like 20 empty method implementations or subclass one of its children, which could be a bit confusing for other developer looking at the test.

Comment: Oh okay. I didn't know it was abstract. If you're using an IDE (I'm assuming you're using Eclipse or NetBeans), it can pull all those abstract methods in for you and you can just stick a comment above them all explaining what you're doing. Not a very programmatic solution, but at least other developers won't be confused by it.