# Compile error while using EasyMock.expect() in very simple example?

Tags: java, unit-testing, compiler-errors, easymock

I am trying a very simple example using [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/), however I simply cannot make it build. I have the following test case:

```
@Test
public void testSomething()
{
    SomeInterface mock = EasyMock.createMock(SomeInterface.class);
    SomeBase expected = new DerivesFromSomeBase();

    EasyMock.expect(mock.send(expected));
}
```

However I get the following error in the `EasyMock.expect(...` line:

```
The method expect(T) in the type EasyMock is not applicable for the arguments (void)
```

Can somebody point me in the correct direction? I am completely lost.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to test `void` methods, call the method you want to test on your mock. Then call the [`expectLastCall()`](http://easymock.org/api/easymock/2.5/org/easymock/EasyMock.html#expectLastCall%28%29) method.

Here's an example:

```
@Test
public void testSomething()
{
    SomeInterface mock = EasyMock.createMock(SomeInterface.class);
    SomeBase expected = new DerivesFromSomeBase();

    mock.send(expected);

    EasyMock.expectLastCall().andAnswer(new IAnswer<Object>() {
        public Object answer() {
            // do additional assertions here
            SomeBase arg1 = (SomeBase) EasyMock.getCurrentArguments()[0];

            // return null because of void
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your example does not compile. `IAnswer` is a generic and needs a template. If I use `IAnswer<Object>` there is not method `getCurrentArguments()` available within the scope of the `answer()` method. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @bjarkef you're right it should be `EasyMock.getCurrentArguments()`. I had a static import so I didn't notice it was missing.

Answer (score 9):

Since your send() method returns void, just call the mock method with expected values and replay:

```
SomeInterface mock = EasyMock.createMock(SomeInterface.class);
SomeBase expected = new DerivesFromSomeBase(); 
mock.send(expected);
replay(mock);
```

Comment: After `replay()` I am then expected to perform the action that would actually cause `mock.send()` to happen. And EasyMock will assert that the same calls as I expect with the same parameters are executed from my class under test?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are mocking an interface, the only purpose in mocking a method would be to return a result from that method. In this case, it appears your 'send' method's return type is void. The 'EasyMock.expect' method is generic and expects a return type, which is causing the compiler to tell you that you can't use a void method because it doesn't have a return type.

For more information, see the EasyMock API documentation at http://easymock.org/api/easymock/3.0/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can't script methods with a void return in that way; check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859031/easymock-void-methods) for a good answer on how you can mock the behavior of your `send` method on your `expected` object.