# Presenter call to rest service testing EasyMock

Tags: gwt, junit, mvp, easymock

I am newbie to gwt, mvp and easymock. I am building an application using MVP pattern inwhich presenter is calling the remote RestService. I want to test presenter function which is calling remote service using EasyMock. Currently, my code looks like

```
    expect(applicationView.get()).andReturn(5);       
    applicationPresenter.setView(applicationView);

    replay(applicationView);

    MyRestService mService = createNiceMock(MyRestService.class);       
    applicationPresenter.setMyRestService(mService);
    applicationPresenter.fetchAllBooks();
    verify(applicationView);
```

I run test and test passes successfully. Am i doing right? How to test the response because service is a RestService interface which returns response in a MethodCallback. My service interface looks like:

```
@Path("/rest-service")
public interface MyRestService extends RestService {
@Path(value="/getAllBooks")
@GET
void getAllBooks(MethodCallback<List<Book>> callback);
```

Please help that my procedure for presenter and server calls testing is right? How to test response and pass the values to Application view? Do I need to pass values to view or just mock the values?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not massively knowledgeable on REST services, but a web service that starts with `get` and returns void seems very odd to me.

That aside, you will need to expect the call to `getAllBooks` as your service is a mock.
From the look of it, the `fetchAllBooks` method instantiates the `MethodCallBack` and then provides it to mock service. So, if you want to make changes to it so that it is in some expected state when the `fetchAllBooks` method continues, you could use `andAnswer()` from the expectation.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
    MyRestService mService = createNiceMock(MyRestService.class);  
            mService.getAllBooks(EasyMock.isA(MethodCallcack.class));
    EasyMock.expectLastCall().andAnswer(new IAnswer() {

        @Override
        public Object answer() throws Throwable {
            final Object[] currentArguments = EasyMock.getCurrentArguments();
            MethodCallback callback = ((MethodCallback)currentArguments[0]);
            //Set whatever you need to on your MethodCallback so that the data makes it back.

            return null;
        }

    });

    //Don't forget to replay
    EasyMock.replay(mService);
```

There is a good stack overflow post about this sort of thing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859031/easymock-void-methods) too